# jsf/richface Mandatory Field in chinese version

Tags: java, jsf, locale, requiredfieldvalidator

I would like to change the default alert message from English to Chinese.
The below is the existing code in my program.

When the required is set true, the alter message is Mandatory Field.

How can i set the locale into Chinese? So all the default message can become Chinese version?

```
<h:inputHidden value="" id="cust_code_hidden" label="Customer" required="true"/>    
<t:message for="cust_code_hidden"/>
```

Customer: Mandatory Field.

The below seem not work, and i don't want use requiredMessage in this case.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getViewRoot().setLocale(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up localization in faces-config.xml:

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>zh_CN</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

Comment: However, i would like to load locale base on my user setting. Any idea on it to code java in program?